# R: Correlation calculation based on two conditions

Tags: r

I need to calculate the correlation for my data set based on two conditions. Below is an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Main = c(0.0089, -0.050667, -0.030379, 0.066484, 0.006439, -0.026076), 
  B = c(NA, 0.0345, -0.0683, -0.052774, 0.014661, -0.040537), 
  C = c(0.0181, 0, -0.056197, 0.040794, 0.03516, -0.022662), 
  D = c(-0.0127, -0.025995, -0.04293, 0.057816, 0.033458, -0.058382)
)
df1
#    Main       B          C          D
# 1  0.008900   NA         0.018100  -0.012700
# 2 -0.050667   0.034500   0.000000  -0.025995
# 3 -0.030379  -0.068300  -0.056197  -0.042930
# 4  0.066484  -0.052774   0.040794   0.057816
# 5  0.006439   0.014661   0.035160   0.033458
# 6 -0.026076  -0.040537  -0.022662  -0.058382
```

I want to get the correlation between `Main` and each of the columns when 1) `Main<0` and 2) when 1) is met, columns `B`, `C`, or `D` do not equals `0`. In this example, for Main and B, row #2, 3 & 6 (df1) fit the rules; for Main and C, row #3 & 6 fit; for Main and D, row #2, 3 & 6 fit.

In Excel, this can be done by using two `if` functions. For example, to calculate the negative correlation between `Main` and `B`, I can use `{=CORREL(IF(A1:A6<0, A1:A6), IF(A1:A6<0, IF(B1:B6<>0, B1:B6)))}`

My actual data set has close to 20 columns like this and will change from time to time. I'm pretty sure R can do it but I've been stuck with this problem for hours. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want done with `NA`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico I'd like to remove NAs.

Comment: then the below code is even better, since `[.data.table` automatically excludes `NA` elements from the subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a=as.matrix(df1)
ind=(a[,1]<0)
a[a==0]=NA
cor(a[ind,1],a[ind,-1],use="pairwise")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
df1[Main < 0 & Reduce(`&`, lapply(df1[ , !"Main", with = FALSE], `!=`, 0)), 
    cor(.SD)]
#      Main  B  C  D
# Main    1  1  1 -1
# B       1  1  1 -1
# C       1  1  1 -1
# D      -1 -1 -1  1
```

(Obviously since the subset is only two points, everything's perfectly correlated -- two points define a unique line)

If you [install the development version of `data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), this can be simplified slightly to:

```
df1[Main < 0 & Reduce(`&`, lapply(df1[ , !"Main"], `!=`, 0)), 
    cor(.SD)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the results seem to be off. The negative correlation between Main and B, C, and D are -0.90953, 1.0, and -0.9452 separately.

Comment: @T-T Only rows 4 & 5 fit your condition. Where do you get those numbers?

Comment: I got them from Excel by using the formula mentioned in my post. For Main and B, row #2, 3 & 6 (df1) fit; for Main and C, row 3 & 6 fit; for  Main and D, row 2, 3 & 6 fit.

Comment: @T-T this is different from your condition that _none_of the columns = 0. The way you defined it in your question is also statistically more natural.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have modified my post to make it clearer. Could you please take a look again?